# Segfault in a for loop over a vector of pointer to objects

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to write a program to create a vector of pointer to objects  and then dereference it to print the values it holds.
But the program is aborting due to seg fault .

The segmentation fault is at the line `cout << p1->rno << endl;` in `display( )` function.

Please help me find out the problem.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
class student
{
  public:
  int rno;
  char name[25];
  student(int r,char *p):rno(r)
  {
     //cout << "Con No is" << ++cnt << endl;
     strcpy(name,p);
  }
  static int cnt;
};

void display(vector<student *> &vec)
{
     vector<student *> :: iterator p;
     student *p1;
     for(p = vec.begin( );p != vec.end( );++p);
     {
       p1 = *p;
       cout << p1->rno << endl;
     }
}
int student :: cnt = 0;

int main( )
{
    vector<student *> vec;
    student *p;
    int i = 0; 
    while(i < 10)
    {
      p = new student(i,"Ganesh");
      vec.push_back(p);
      i++;
    }
    display(vec);
    system("PAUSE 100");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug a little ? Any idea in which part it appears to fail ?

Comment: The statement "cout << p1->rno << endl"; is causing the fault.

Comment: @user175816 this is relevant information - please edit your question and add this precise detail.

Answer (score 6):

You made a typo

```
for(p = vec.begin( );p != vec.end( );++p);
//                                       ^
```

Your *for loop* has empty body.

P.S. I would suggest you to turn on warnings, it can helps you to avoid such typos. For example, clang throws the following warning:

> warning: for loop has empty body [-Wempty-body]